# Invalid Firebase path: Firebase paths must not contain '.', '#', '$', '[', or ']'

Tags: firebase, app-inventor

I am creating an app on appinventor with firebase and I have an error returned when I introduce an email to the firebase, how to resolve it?

`Invalid Firebase path:  Firebase paths must not contain '.', '#', '$', '[', or ']'`

Comment: You can't have any of the above characters in your key. So your email, which contains `.` cannot be used as the key. You have to use username or uid as your key in your data structure.

Comment: Don't use the email value as a key or mutate it to remove the `.` from it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This an example for storing to firebase if a value contains `. # $ [ ]`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using email address as a key in Firebase Realtime Database is not a very good idea.  Email addresses are problematic because they are not case sensitive, users may change them over time, and as you've see, they contain invalid characters.

Instead, you should use some other identifier, such as an automated push id, or some other unique id.  You can store the email address as a child value within the space you create for each user, and you can query users to look for a specific email address later, if you like.

If you really must use an email address as a child key, you'll need to encode the string some way in order to remove the invalid characters, and always remember to encode email address strings the same way when searching for the user by that email.

Answer (score 0):

Simple, before using the email address replace all the '.' with '1'.

Therefore this email "example@email.com" will look like "example@email1com".

This can also be done to replace any other characters that are illegal.

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

this seems to work

```
Utils.EncodeString(user.email)
```

cheers

Answer (score 0):

You receive this exception because email contain invalid characters such as '.' and '@' which are invalid to the firebase database. Instead, use user id. 
Simply use `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()`.
Hopefully, the problem should go away.

Answer (score 0):

I received this error while trying to use `orderBy`, as i copy-pasted from the UI something like:

```
.collection("my_collection").orderBy("", "asc")
```

forgot to fill out the `""` inside it ...

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same error. I resolved it in a simple step, it seems that you might be using email address as the key (which I did in my case) is not a very good practice it would be better to use any other variables as key which doesnot contain the special characters.

Hope its helpful